# windows command line csr file certreq.exe output bad format on Subject ,Issue to, and issue by

Tags: command, certificate, csr

Windows command line CSR file

```
`certreq.exe -new C:\Certs\template.inf C:\Certs\mydomain.txt.csr`
```

returns:

> bad format on Subject ,Issue to, and issue by this format

The `template.inf` has
`Subject = "CN=mydomain.com, OU=IT, O=My Company,  L=my city, S=my state, C=US`

I get this on

`Issue to: CN=mydomain.com, OU=IT, O=My Company,  L=my city, S=my state, C=US in 1 line.`

same for
`issue by: CN=mydomain.com, OU=IT, O=My Company,  L=my city, S=my state, C=US`

also

`Subject : CN=mydomain.com, OU=IT, O=My Company,  L=my city, S=my state, C=US`

With the IIS server certificates mmc. I get the below, the desired result

```
CN = mydomain.com
OU = IT
O = My Company
L = my city
S = my state
C = US
```

All the documentation says to put it all in 1 line in the template  file.
Can some one please advice?

Answer (score 0):

Take the following `*.inf` as source template to generate a web server certificate:

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"

[Strings]
szOID_SAN = "2.5.29.17"
szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE = "2.5.29.37"
szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"

[NewRequest]
Exportable=False
SMIME=False
Hashalgorithm=SHA256
KeyLength=2048
KeySpec = AT_KEYEXCHANGE 
KeyUsage = "CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE | CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE"
RequestType=PKCS10; PKCS10 or CMC
Subject="CN=mydomain.com, OU=IT, O=My Company, L=my city, S=my state, C=US"
ProviderName="Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider"
MachineKeySet=True

[Extensions]
%szOID_SAN%="{text}"
_continue_ = "DNS=mydomain.com&"
%szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE%="{text}"
_continue_ = "%szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH%,"
```

I used your subject and for better compatibility with browsers I also added the `CN` value as `DNS Host Name` to the *subject alternative name*.

As `MachineKeySet` is set to `True` the following command must be run with administrative privileges:

```
& certreq.exe -New ".\Template.inf" "CertificateSigningRequest.p10"
```